# How to use the npm replace command in windows instead of the windows replace.exe command

Tags: windows, npm

I can't use directly the npm's replace package in windows because `replace` command is using `replace.exe` of windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$APPDATA/npm/replace` command instead of `replace`command. It will call the 'replace' of npm and not the one of windows

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26301803)

Comment: It answer to the question because its not a bypass or a trick. It just the way to call the npm's replace command in windows.